# Lua dissector for HTTP, having trouble finding end of string

Tags: string, http, lua, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to separate the string data in an HTTP protocol in wireshark using lua and I am not having success finding the end of the string, this is what I currently have

```
HTTP_protocol = Proto("ourHTTP", "HTTPProtocol")

first =ProtoField.string("HTTP_protocol.first", "first", base.ASCII)
second =ProtoField.string("HTTP_protocol.second", "second", base.ASCII)
HTTP_protocol.fields = {first}

function HTTP_protocol.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
 length = buffer:len()

 if length ==0 then return end
pinfo.cols.protocol = HTTP_protocol.name
local subtree = tree:add(HTTP_protocol, buffer(), "HTTPProtocol data ")
local string_length

for i = 0, length - 1, 1 do
  if (buffer(i,1):uint() == '\r') then
    string_length = i - 0
    break
  end
end
subtree:add(first, buffer(0,string_length))

end
porttable = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
porttable:add(80, HTTP_protocol)
```

i have tried searching for '\r', '\0' and '\n' but no matter what I still get all the strings inputed as one. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `buffer(i,1):uint() == '\r'` looks suspicious

Comment: Of course. But I’m not sure which terminator to search for. None seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `0x0D` instead. That's the ASCII code for `\r`. So it will end up as

```lua
if (buffer(i,1):uint() == 0x0D) then
```

In Wireshark:

[image: Picture of Wireshark with proper lineshift]